# Surface has Euler characteristic 2 iff equal to sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a connected (not necessarily compact) surface with or without boundary. Is it true that $\Sigma$ is homeomorphic to the sphere if it has euler characteristic $\chi(\Sigma)\geq 2$?

I could't find a definite answer if we don't request $\Sigma$ to be compact.

Comment: If your surfaces are connected and compact, possibly with boundary, then this is true by the formulas $\chi=2-2g-b$ for orientable and $\chi=2-g-b$ for non-orientable surfaces with $b$ boundary components and positive genus/cross-cap sum $g$ for non-spherical surfaces.

Comment: Yes, but is there a counterexample in the non-compact (connected) case?

Comment: I think adding a puncture (on the interior) increase the Euler characteristic by $1$ so a twice punctured torus will have Euler characteristic $\chi(T^2\setminus\{p\})=2-2(1)+2(1)=2$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that..
Shouldn't be the Euler characteristic of a twice punctured torus be -2 though?

Comment: Punctures are not the same as boundary components. When you lose compactness you also potentially lose the possibility of putting a triangulation on the manifold, so weird things can happen. If it helps, you can think of the puncture instead as being a cusp which extends out to infinity from the surface in some ambient space (so swapping boundedness for closedness). I can't find a reference at the moment for the formula for Euler characteristic of a punctured surface except for [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361121/).

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76043/) also illustrates why compactness is important (even for homotopy invariance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Punctures and boundary components both decrease the Euler characteristic, and the results are homotopy equivalent. For example, $\chi(S^2) = 2$. Adding a puncture gives $\chi(\mathbb{R}^2) = 1$. Adding a boundary component gives $\chi(D^2) = 1$. Puncturing the torus once gives a wedge of $2$ circles, with Euler characteristic $-1$, and puncturing it again gives a wedge of $3$ circles, with Euler characteristic $-2$.

More generally, any noncompact connected surface is homotopy equivalent to a connected $1$-dimensional CW complex, or equivalently a connected graph. These are in turn homotopy equivalent to a wedge of some number of circles, and hence have Euler characteristic at most $1$. (There may be infinitely many circles involved, in which the Euler characteristic is not even well-defined; think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus countably many points, for example.)

Comment: So if $\Sigma$ is any connected surface (compact or non compact) that has a well-defined Euler characteristic, we have $\chi(\Sigma)\leq 2$ and the equality holds if and only if $\Sigma$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$. Is that right?

Comment: @Pete: yes, that's right.